# How to solve MySQL showing non-existing data?

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL query to show me the files that have been uploaded and are of type V.

The files's information is stored in the vector_data table.

Currently it contains only 1 row.

Nevertheless, it is showing 3 files as a result.

Please see the query and tables below.

The data does not need to be ordered.

It should show all the files uploaded by the user specified in the query.

query

```
select v.*
     , j.Name ProjectName
     , t.Name as TypeName 
  from vector_data v
     , project j
     , product_type t
 where v.Type = t.ID 
   and t.Type = 'V' 
   and v.Status =  'Finished' 
   and v.Uploader = 'user@gmail.com' 
 order 
    by ProjectName
     , v.FileName
```

Current output

```
| ID |                  Type                  |  EPSG | FileName | Date |  Size |  ChunkCount |  Status  |  UploadFolder |  DownloadPath |  Identifier |
|----|----------------------------------------|-------|---------------|--------------|--------------|------------|-------------|----------|----------|--------------|
| 40 | 8 | 4326 | plot_boundary_1.geojson | 06/27/2016 | 74137 | 1 | Finished | "" | /var/www/html/uas_data/uploads/products/2016_Corpus_Christi_Cotton_and_Sorghum///04/12/2016//GeoJSON/plot_boundary_1 | https://test/products/2016_Corpus_Christi_Cotton_and_Sorghum///04/12/2016//GeoJSON/plot_boundary_1/plot_boundary_1.geojson | 74137-plot_boundary1geojson | 100 | 2021-03-22 18:48:44 | user@gmail.com | 2016 Corpus Christi Cotton and Sorghum | GeoJSON |
| 40 | 8 | 4326 | plot_boundary_1.geojson | 06/27/2016 | 74137 | 1 | Finished | "" | /var/www/html/uas_data/uploads/products/2016_Corpus_Christi_Cotton_and_Sorghum///04/12/2016//GeoJSON/plot_boundary_1 | https://test/products/2016_Corpus_Christi_Cotton_and_Sorghum///04/12/2016//GeoJSON/plot_boundary_1/plot_boundary_1.geojson | 74137-plot_boundary1geojson | 100 | 2021-03-22 18:48:44 | user@gmail.com | 2016 Weslaco Tomato                    | GeoJSON |
| 40 | 8 | 4326 | plot_boundary_1.geojson | 06/27/2016 | 74137 | 1 | Finished | "" | /var/www/html/uas_data/uploads/products/2016_Corpus_Christi_Cotton_and_Sorghum///04/12/2016//GeoJSON/plot_boundary_1 | https://test/products/2016_Corpus_Christi_Cotton_and_Sorghum///04/12/2016//GeoJSON/plot_boundary_1/plot_boundary_1.geojson | 74137-plot_boundary1geojson | 100 | 2021-03-22 18:48:44 | user@gmail.com | 2019 Amarillo Wheat - Irrigation Land  | GeoJSON |
```

project

```
| ID |                  Name                  |  Crop |  PlantingDate |  HarvestDate |  Description |  CenterLat |  CenterLng  |  MinZoom |  MaxZoom |  DefaultZoom |
|----|----------------------------------------|-------|---------------|--------------|--------------|------------|-------------|----------|----------|--------------|
|  1 | 2016 Corpus Christi Cotton and Sorghum |    43 | 04-01-2016    | ""           | ""           |  42.782301 |  -95.560600 |       17 |       25 |           19 |
|  2 | 2019 Amarillo Wheat - Irrigation Land  |    40 | 11-08-2018    | ""           | ""           |  71.190498 | -122.084000 |       17 |       25 |           19 |
|  3 | 2016 Weslaco Tomato                    |    44 | 01-01-2016    | ""           | ""           |  26.157201 |  -57.163600 |       17 |       25 |           19 |
```

product_type

```
| ID |          Name         |  Type |
|----|-----------------------|-------|
|  1 | RGB Ortho             | R     |
|  2 | RGB DEM               | R     |
|  3 | MULTI Ortho           | R     |
|  4 | NDVI                  | R     |
|  5 | ExG                   | R     |
|  6 | Thermal Ortho         | R     |
|  7 | Canopy Cover Rendered | R     |
|  8 | GeoJSON               | V     |
```

vector_data

```
| ID |  Type |  EPSG |         FileName        |    Date    |  Size |  ChunkCount |  Status  |  TempFolder |                                                     UploadFolder                                                     |                                                            DownloadPath                                                            |          Identifier         |  Progress |      LastUpdate     |    Uploader    |
|----|-------|-------|-------------------------|------------|-------|-------------|----------|-------------|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|-----------------------------|-----------|---------------------|----------------|
| 40 |     8 |  4326 | plot_boundary_1.geojson | 06/27/2016 | 74137 |           1 | Finished | ""          | /var/www/html/uas_data/uploads/products/2016_Corpus_Christi_Cotton_and_Sorghum///04/12/2016//GeoJSON/plot_boundary_1 | https://test/uploads/products/2016_Corpus_Christi_Cotton_and_Sorghum///04/12/2016//GeoJSON/plot_boundary_1/plot_boundary_1.geojson | 74137-plot_boundary1geojson |       100 | 2021-03-22 18:48:44 | user@gmail.com |
```

Comment: We stopped writing queries this way circa 1992. Come. Join us.

Comment: Yes, if you could format your query so it's not all on one line that would be helpful...

Comment: And for the love of humanity, store dates as dates

Comment: Lol, I understand I need to improve my MySQL abilities. Thank you for the recommendations seriously. I can tell you both have way more experience than I do. Could you please fix my query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting 3 rows, 1 for each of the rows of the table `project` because in your query you did not add the link between `vector_data` and `project`, which (I guess) is the column `crop`:

```
select v.*, 
       j.Name ProjectName,
       t.Name as TypeName 
from vector_data v
inner join project j on j.crop = v.ID
inner join product_type t on v.Type = t.ID
where v.Type = 'V' and v.Status =  'Finished' and v.Uploader = 'user@gmail.com' 
order by ProjectName, v.FileName
```

I used proper join clauses instead of the archaic implicit joins in your code.